# Adding third party documentation to Xcode 5 via atom feed

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, xcode5, atom-feed

Is there a way to add 3rd party documentation published via an atom feed (e.g.  http://pandamonia.github.io/BlocksKit/us.pandamonia.BlocksKit.atom) to Xcode 5?

In Xcode 4 it could be added [like this](http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22270990-How-to-add-MAT-iOS-SDK-api-documentation-to-Xcode-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app in the Mac App store that lets you do that conveniently. It's called Docs for Xcode...

http://documancer.com/xcode/